# Setting max coredump size on AIX doesn't work

Tags: aix

I googled to set the coredump max size on AIX to 20 MBytes:

```
0:root@SERVER:/root # su - username
$ ulimit -a
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         131072
stack(kbytes)        32768
memory(kbytes)       32768
coredump(blocks)     2097151
nofiles(descriptors) 2000
threads(per process) unlimited
processes(per user)  unlimited
$ exit
0:root@SERVER:/root # chuser core=40960 username
0:root@SERVER:/root # su - username             
$ ulimit -a
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         131072
stack(kbytes)        32768
memory(kbytes)       32768
coredump(blocks)     40960
nofiles(descriptors) 2000
threads(per process) unlimited
processes(per user)  unlimited
$ exit
0:root@SERVER:/root #
```

but later a coredump, sized about ~800 MByte was created by this user.

**My question**: Why? Is the 40960=20MB? -> 1=0,5 KByte? Or could was that the problem that the user probably didn't logged out/in after the max coredump size change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process which created the core dump was probably started before you changed the ulimit, and hence was running from a shell or environment with the old setting.